# Mysql выборка с вложенным запросом + node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

Есть таблицы (players,items,player_items)

```
PLAYERS:
    ----------------
    | id | name    |
    ----------------
    | 1  | Player1 | 
    | 2  | Player2 |
    ----------------

ITEMS:
    ----------------
    | id | name    |
    ----------------
    | 1  | Item_1  | 
    | 2  | Item_2  |
    ----------------
PLAYER_ITEMS:
    ----------------
    | id | player_id | item_id |
    ----------------------------
    | 1  | 1         | 1       | 
    | 2  | 1         | 2       | 
    | 3  | 2         | 1       |
    ----------------------------
```

Делаю запрос

```
pool.query('SELECT players.id,
                   players.name, 
                   t_items.id AS item_id, 
                   t_items.name AS item_name 
            FROM players LEFT JOIN player_items ON player_items.player_id = players.id 
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM items) t_items ON t_items.id = player_items.item_id 
            WHERE players.id = ?', [ID], (error,result) => {
               if (error) throw error;
               if(result.length > 0){
                 const PLAYERS = [];
                 result.forEach(el => {
                     PLAYERS.push({player_id:id,player_name: name, player_items:[{...}]})
                     Необходимо получить массив - 
                     {
                      "player_id": "1",
                      "player_name": "Player1",
                      "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1},{item_id:2,item_name: Item_2}],
                     },
                     {
                      "player_id": "2",
                      "player_name": "Player2",
                      "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1}],
                     }//и так далее
                 });
               }
            });
```

Необходимо получить массив

```
  {
   "player_id": "1",
   "player_name": "Player1",
   "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1},{item_id:2,item_name: Item_2}],
  },
  {
   "player_id": "2",
   "player_name": "Player2",
   "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1}],
  }//и так далее
```

Сейчас массив получается такой:

```
  {
   "player_id": "1",
   "player_name": "Player1",
   "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1}],
  },
  {
   "player_id": "1",
   "player_name": "Player1",
   "player_items": [{item_id:2,item_name: Item_2}],
  },
  {
   "player_id": "2",
   "player_name": "Player2",
   "player_items": [{item_id:1,item_name: Item_1}],
  }//и так далее
```

Comment: А вопрос какой?

Comment: Как получить массив данных ( добавил в вопросе )

Comment: Вы хотите ответ от БД преобразовать и составить нужный вам массив или из БД приходит не то, что ожидаете?

Comment: Из бд приходят данные,  но они дублируются как в последнем блоке кода ( приходит 3 строки вместо 2 строк, но я думаю это уже нужно делать не в запросе а циклами в node) , мне нужно скомпоновать массив так как в предпоследнем блоке кода

Comment: Что вы используете для работы с бд? Это sequelize?

Comment: Группировка по второй таблице, потом JOIN к первой. `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(..))`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(..)) принцип понятен, такой вопрос, это не скажется на производительности в худшую сторону?